# Dynamic google map icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables one with markers another with marker icons. The icons are stored in the database as blob, where markers and icons are mapped by the ID's. The issue i am having is mapping the icons by id and markers type to the correct.

for example:

I'm trying to implement something like the following https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

what i have done so far is the following

converting the overlay results(which i get via ajax and push to overlayRes object)

```
var binary = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < overlayRes.length; i++) {  
 var iconData = overlayRes[i].OverlayData.replace(/[^A-Fa-f0-9]/g, "");
  for(var i=0; i< iconData.length / 2; i++){
    var h = iconData.substr(i * 2, 2);
    binary[i] = parseInt(h, 16);
 }
}

byteArray = new Uint8Array(binary);
img = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));

 var icons = {
      K: {
        icon: img
      },
      L: {
        icon: img
      },
    };
//markers
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: features[i].position,
            icon: icons[features[i].type].icon, // need to get different markers per marker type 
            map: map
          });
```

TIA

Comment: You need to move `createObjectURL` inside `for` loop of `overlayRes` and push each processed item into `icons[]`

Comment: Hi @Viney, ok i managed to update the icons object, not sure if this is a googlemaps icon issue, but its not displaying the icon since the icons { icon: "img: "blob:http://site.local/87e52273-46e5-4a05-9736-70b7264f11f6"} but when i  hardcode the actual image it works ie. image path. might this be a googlemap icon issue

Comment: Try `img = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/png' }));` instead